# Name button as value of String

Tags: android, string, button

i have weird question. I want to make Button (for example) named as value of string a.
Is there any possibility to do that?

```
    String a = "d2";
    Button a;// i want to make buton named d2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. Java does not accept creating any kind of objects with names from another variable.

What you can do is make a HashMap

And them add the String as a key.

Ex:

```
Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
HashMap<String, Button> myMap = new HashMap<>();
String s = "d2" 
myMap.put(s, mButton);
```

And to reference the button you can do:

```
myMap.get(s);
```

Comment: Thanks for info and idea, it may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

After you have created a button in your main xml file, use the following code :

```
 String a = "desired text here";
 Button b = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button);
 b.setText(a);
```